# Mysql blob picture to awt.image followed by awt.image to blob without size alteration

Tags: java, mysql, image, awt, blob

I am currently working on a Swing program where I store pictures as blobs in a mysql database. For reasons too long to describe here, from time to time I have to save back in the database pictures that were previously loaded from it.

Here is a sample code of how I am currently loading from / saving to the DB in java :

```
package oldutils;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import utils.SingletonConnection;

public class DisplayImage2 extends JFrame
{
private Connection        connection = null;
private ResultSet         result     = null;
private PreparedStatement statement  = null;
private Blob              blob       = null;
private ImageIcon         imageIcon  = null;
private JLabel            labelPhoto = null;
private Image             image      = null;
private String            query      = null;
private byte[]            byteArray  = null;

public DisplayImage2()
    {
        super("Image Display");
        setSize(600, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        connection = SingletonConnection.getConnection();
        try
            {
                query = "SELECT * FROM photo WHERE pkPhoto=?";
                statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                statement.setInt(1, 61);
                result = statement.executeQuery();

                while ( result.next() )
                    {
                        byteArray = result.getBytes("photoImage");
                        image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(byteArray);
                        imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
                    }

                labelPhoto = new JLabel();
                labelPhoto.setIcon(imageIcon);
                add(labelPhoto);
                setVisible(true);

                try
                    {
                        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), 
                                    image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                        Graphics2D bImageGraphics = bufferedImage.createGraphics(); // Obtain graphics
                        bImageGraphics.drawImage(image, null, null); //Draw Image into BufferedImage
                        RenderedImage rImage = (RenderedImage) bufferedImage; // Cast to rendered image
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        ImageIO.write(rImage, "png", bas);
                        byteArray = bas.toByteArray();
                        blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(byteArray);
                    }
                catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                query = "INSERT INTO photo (photoName, photoImage) VALUES(?,?)";
                statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                statement.setString(1, "Image Test");
                statement.setBlob(2, blob);
                statement.executeUpdate();
            }
        catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new DisplayImage2();
    }
  }
```

The issue is that the pictures are first carefully "crafted" regarding compression rate/size /quality as JPEG pictures before being inserted first in the table. But using the method in the above code, with ImageIO.write(), I am forced to either grow the original size of the picture when resaving it (as "PNG" for example) or shrinking it (as "JPG") and losing quality. Is there no way to take the image bits from the DB to memory, using them and then putting them back as the original blobs to the DB without any alteration either in size or quality?

Comment: "For reasons too long to describe here" -> there should be an acronym for this! :-) FRTLTDH

Comment: I agree with that, you've just invented a new awesome acronym ;)

Comment: someone correct me if I am wrong, but it seems that you're storing a compressed format in the DB but your swing app, under the hood, will actually generate a bitmap to show it. So what you probably need is a way to save/restore the image directly to the BufferedImage?

Comment: Your diagnosis is completely correct. That's what I am doing, but the last part of it is the one that gives me headaches...

Comment: what I don't get here is why do you have to convert the byteArray to png to save it as a BLOB again. Can't you just save the same byteArray you've read from "byteArray = result.getBytes("photoImage");"? (even that does not make sense too...)

Comment: @Leo You are absolutely correct and you saved my day! My save method in the code above is saving any image loaded in memory (either already in the DB or not).  But now I can simply check if it was already saved before and only do `code`blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(byteArray);`code`. Sometimes overcomplicating :)) Thanks a lot!! If you could copy paste your last comment in an answer, i could vote for it.

Comment: Don't worry about that. There wasn't a real problem here, right? :-) I think you were just in need of a second opinion. Sometimes we stare so long watching the code while all you need is just a cup of coffee :-)

Comment: It's probably fair if you write the answer yourself and accept your own answer. At least, people won't come here to try to solve something that's already solved ;-) cheers

Comment: Okay, if you insist I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered by Leo in his comments, but as he is so humble to deny the vote points, I am writing it myself so that it could help someone...

All that is needed (assuming that the byteArray is still in memory) is skipping all the ImageBuffer/Graphics/.. creation and manipulation part, reusing the same ByteArray[] and simply obtaining a blob as before and then saving it.

```
public DisplayImage2()
{
super("Image Display");
setSize(600, 600);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
connection = SingletonConnection.getConnection();
// LOAD FROM BLOB
try
    {
        query = "SELECT * FROM photo WHERE pkPhoto=?";
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setInt(1, 61);
        result = statement.executeQuery();

        while ( result.next() )
            {
                byteArray = result.getBytes("photoImage");
                image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(byteArray);
                imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
            }

        labelPhoto = new JLabel();
        labelPhoto.setIcon(imageIcon);
        add(labelPhoto);
        setVisible(true);
        // SAVE TO BLOB

        blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(byteArray);

        query = "INSERT INTO photo (photoName, photoImage) VALUES(?,?)";
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setString(1, "Image Test");
        statement.setBlob(2, blob);
        statement.executeUpdate();
    }

catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```